# Leading spaces are not displayed in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I tried the following angularJS code sample.

```
<div ng-app="">

  <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
  <p>Name : <input  type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>
```

This works fine but when I enter a string with leading spaces it will simply trim them out. How can I use this to display a string with leading spaces. (btw I don't want to display string with only spaces)

Comment: The [text input docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) specify an `ng-trim` boolean-valued attribute. I'm pretty sure this would not trim all-whitespace strings tho if set to `false`, and I'm not familiar enough with Angular to know what to do to put in the more custom behavior of not trimming strings if they aren't all whitespace. Also, your `<input>` needs a `type` attribute (in your case, probably `"text"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ng-trim="false"` to your `input`. Confirm that ng-trim worked by changing to a `pre` wrapped with quotes.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-trim="false" placeholder="Enter name here">

<pre>Hello '{{name}}'</pre>
```

Here's the code to ignore fully blank names:

```
<pre>Hello '<span ng-show="name.trim().length > 0">{{name}}</span>'</pre>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R0p6E7OkY6eEC13FqtBo?p=preview)

Comment: Wouldn't this still display all-whitespace string values?

Comment: Yeah It will display all white space texts also. I think we have to check for those manually right ? If not is there a cool way to do that also ?

Comment: @ajp15243 try the plunker - what doesn't it do correctly as asked by @prime?

Comment: @AndyGaskell From the question: `(btw I don't want to display string with only spaces)`. If you just type spaces then it still displays the spaces in the `{{name}}` model output, which prime doesn't want.

Comment: @AndyGaskell It will display strings with all spaces (kinda empty string) . I wanted to avoid that too. But your answer is enough for me now. If you can please let us know how to avoid that case also.

Comment: @prime found a much cleaner way - updated the answer again. I'm done I swear!

Comment: yeah.. that way is much clear , ha haa :D . please share if you find another cool way :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not angular that is trimming your spaces, it is HTML not rendering multiple spaces.

Change your code to the following and you will see your spaces:

```
<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input  ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<pre>Hello {{name}}</pre>

</div>
```

Comment: No, with `pre` you do not see leading spaces.

Comment: But this will not solve the problem if there are leading spaces. This works fine and display strings like `"abc      def    gh"`  as it is , when my given code display it as "abc def gh". I want to know how to display a String with leading spaces. spaces in the beginning of the String(or last).

Comment: ah, yes, I guess angular does trim leading strings from inputs. `ng-trim="false"` it is